# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it [::1]:44300"}

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, iis-express

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://localhost:44300/" + "api/color");
var cert = new X509Certificate2("C:/certificates/mylocalsite.local.pfx", "");
webRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
string response = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

I use this code and get the following error on the 4th line:

> InnerException = {"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it [::1]:44300"}
>
> Additional information: Unable to connect to the remote server

Thanks for your help

Comment: Check if the URL "https://localhost:44300/api/color" is accessible from the server or pc where you are running the code

Comment: i am running on my virtual machine using visual studio 2013(console web API application).Thanks for your help

Comment: Could you please  anyone help on this issue ?

Comment: did you enable an encryption key?

Comment: How to enable ? could you suggest ?